# Is there information such as Operation Mode (Booting Mode) in the device tree?

Tags: kernel, proc, system-information, device-tree

Good morning.
I am studying Device Tree of Kernel.
I use an ARM board.
According to the information of Operation Mode(Booting Mode) Register, the device medium used for booting the ARM board is set differently.

> Example)
>    Operation Mode(Booting Mode) Register: 0x01 -> eMMc Booting
>       Operation Mode(Booting Mode) Register: 0x02 -> SD Booting
>       Operation Mode(Booting Mode) Register: 0x03 -> USB Booting

Is there an example of using this information in the Kernel's Device Tree?
Or is there an appropriate example to read Operation Mode (Booting Mode) from Kernel?

Comment: What processor are you using? On the imx233 the μP will check the boot mode register very early in the boot process. The μP will then use this info to load the boot loader which then loads the device tree and the kernel. I guess yours is somewhat similar, so do you want to know the contents of the boot register AFTER the OS is loaded?

Comment: @jc__:Yes. That's right. To do that, I created an properties called /bootmode in the device tree. Then read the Operation Mode(Booting Mode) register from u-boot. I am also entering a value for the /bootmode properties of the device tree with the `fdt set` command of u-boot. And after booting, I read the value of /proc/device-tree/bootmode. But I doubt whether this is the right way to do it.